# Supplier INT returning the value that I enter + Predicate that tells if the number I enter is prime or not

Tags: java, primes, predicate, supplier

I have the next task:

**Write a Supplier of type  that returns a number read by screen with a block lambda expression**

**Write a Predicate that tells us if the entered number is a prime with a block expression that has a for loop. Apply it to the supplier's result**.

**Must return:**

*Write one integer per screen
24
number generated by supplier 24 is not prime*

**or**

*Write an integer per screen
23
The number generated by the supplierScreen 23 is primo*

Depending on whether the number entered is prime or not.

The code I made is the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.function.Predicate;


public class Ejercicio4 {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
     
    Supplier <Integer> numeroPorPantalla = () ->{
    int n;   
    System.out.println("Escriba un número entero por pantalla");
    n=teclado.nextInt();
    return n;
     
    };
   
   Predicate<Integer> esPrimo = (n) -> {
    int a = 0;
    int i;
    
    for (i=1; i<= n; i++) {
        if (n % 1 == 0) {
            a++;
        }
    }
       if (a != 2) {
           System.out.println("The supplier number "+numeroPorPantalla.get()+" is not prime");
       } else {
           System.out.println("The supplier number "+numeroPorPantalla.get()+" is prime");
       }
        return true ;
 };
   
     System.out.println("");
     System.out.print(esPrimo.test(numeroPorPantalla.get()));
   
    
    }
    

    }
```

And the problems I have when running are:

- it asks me to enter 2 times the value, when it should only be one.
- the FOR loop is not working well for me because it always returns that it is not prime
- It also returns the "true" of the preach and it should not return anything.

I am grateful for any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

1. 2nd invocation of **numeroPorPantalla** is in

`System.out.println("The supplier number "+numeroPorPantalla.get()+"is prime");`

You can write `n` to console instead invoking supplier twice

2. `if (n % 1 == 0)` - remainder of dividing int numbers by one is always 0